# iOS Development: Strange problem with authenticating Game Center user

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, gamekit, game-center

I'm building an iPhone game that supports Game Center (GC).  When the app launches, I try to authenticate the local player...

```
 if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
    {
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
         {
             [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuth:) withArg: NULL error: error];
         }];
    }
```

Everything seemed to be working well.  If the user wasn't signed into GC when the app launched, the app would display a dialog box giving them three options...

1. Sign into existing account
2. Create an account
3. Cancel

This is the desired behavior, but while I was testing, I clicked the "Cancel" option and now the authentication process errors out every time with the following error "The requested operation has been cancelled."  Even when I delete the app and reinstall it, it still errors out and that dialog box never pops ups now.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It turns out that is apple undocumented behavior.

After 3 times a user press cancel in a row, he has to go to the Game Center app and connect from there.

Go Figure.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I had run into the same issue.

Comment: What is the solution if you need to sign into a sandbox account, and the Game Center app doesn't give you that option? I may be in a similar situation, except I see a `nil` error when I try to authenticate in the app. No modal sign-in dialog, nothing.

Comment: You can only sign in in sandbox mode when your app is build for debugging/adhoc. AppStore builds won't let you access the GameCenter sandbox for your app.